# runtime invocation of method with arguments in groovy

Tags: groovy, dynamic, gstring

For simplicity let's say I have code similar to this:

```
def testMethod(String txt) {
    return txt;
}
public String evaluate(String expression) {
    //String result = "${testMethod('asdasdasd')}";
    String result = "${expression}";
    return result;
}
```

I need the expression value which is passed to method "evaluate" to be executed.

in case of calling

```
// everything works perfectly well,
String result = "${testMethod('samplestring')}";
```

in case of calling

```
// (when expression = testMethod) - everything works perfectly well,
String result = "${expression}"("samplestring");
```

in case of calling

```
// (when expression = testMethod('samplestring'))  - it's not working.
// I see testMethod('samplestring') as the result, but I need it to be evaluated.
String result = "${expression}"
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus should work as well;

```
Eval.me( "${expression}" )
```

#### Edit

As pointed out, this won't work as it stands, you need to pass in the script that contains the method with `Eval.x` like so:

```
def testMethod(String txt) {
    txt
}

public String evaluate(String expression) {
    String result = Eval.x( this, "x.${expression}" )
    result
}

println evaluate( "testMethod('samplestring')" )
```

That will print `samplestring`

Comment: But I think this way you cannot call a method in the expression string, which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @epidemian You're right...  Updated my answer to use `Eval.x` instead

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`GroovyShell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) class for this purpose, but you will need to define a Binding AFAIK. This works in the Groovy Console:

```
def testMethod(txt) {
    "$txt!";
}

def evaluate(String expression) {
    def binding = new Binding(['testMethod': testMethod])
    new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(expression)
}

evaluate('testMethod("Hello World")');
```